# My nether portal spawned inside of a cave?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making/placing portals in the nether every 125 blocks so I have a checkpoint of portals every 1000 blocks in the overworld.

The Y axis of my portal are is at 120, like in the screenshot below.[image: Picture of my portal in the nether]

Now, when I entered that portal, it spawned me inside of the cave. 
(the screenshot shows no portal on it since I removed it, but the obsidian is the original location of the spawned portal)
[image: Spawn area of the exit portal]

I decided to dig straight up and try to look for a reason why I spawned in the cave and I'm just seeing an area that is perfectly fine for a portal to spawn in.

[image: The surface above the portal I spawned in]

My question is **why did the game decided to spawn a portal in a cave?** Are there some checks that the game does? All I know is if it has a space for it, it goes there.

If it matters, the game version I'm running on is 1.14.4.

Answer (score 4):

Nether portals prefer generating on the same height as in the other dimension. So if you create your portal below y=64 in the Nether, it is likely to be generated in a cave in the Overworld.

> The closest valid position in 3D distance is always picked.
>
> – [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_portal#Portal_search_and_creation) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Nether_portal&oldid=1429014#Portal_search_and_creation))

Comment: But my entry portal is at Y120, the exit portal location doesn't make sense at all of that's the case.

Comment: Oh yes, you even wrote that in the question. Then I don't know. This might be a bug.

Comment: The wiki (the one you linked, thank you) says the game looks for a 3x4 space to make a valid spawn. Both the cave and the top satisfy this. Maybe the game just lazily checked the area and probably this is a bug. Thank you for your answer, regardless.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated, but a 1×4 area of completely flat ground with nothing on it definitely is a valid portal spawn location.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you create a portal in the Nether, it will compare where you made the portal in the Nether (using the 8-block distance trick everyone knows and loves), and place it in the Overworld. Usually, it will start at Y=0, then keep repeating and checking until it reaches a place that has enough space (kind of like how the game loads the player when you load into a world). This is usually why people load on the surface, because there's almost always a definite chance that there is enough space (because (duh) it's the surface).

Although I'm no coding master, this has been my experience for years. Hopefully, this answers your question.

Comment: One thing I would recommend though is to checkmark which option helped you the most...